# Docker --rm not cleaning up when background process is running

Tags: docker

Without making the title too long, here is the scenario...

I have two scripts:

1. The first script (`host_startup.sh`) checks whether a website is up. When it finally posts, then it opens the website in the default browser:

   ```
   URL=http://localhost:9876
   until contents=$(wget -q --spider --no-check-certificate "$URL")
   do
     sleep 1
   done
   xdg-open ${URL} &
   ```
2. The second script (`run.sh`) starts the `host_startup` script and then starts up a Docker container which serves up a webpage at the aforementioned address:

   ```
   (../../host_startup.sh) &
   docker run --rm -it \
       -p 9786:9786 \
       company:image
   ```

Note that the docker command runs with the `--rm` flag. However, when I run the `run.sh` script, and Ctrl+C the process, the Docker image is still running... Specifically, `docker ps` shows the container still.

I would like Ctrl+C to stop the container and clean it up.

I thought that the container would stop and cleanup because I put the `host_startup.sh` script in the background, NOT the `docker run` command...

Please tell me how I can achieve the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Appearantly "Bash does not forward signals like SIGTERM to processes it is currently waiting on".

So you could modify your run.sh to:

```
(../../host_startup.sh) &
exec docker run --rm -it \
    -p 9786:9786 \
    company:image
```

Which would replace the fork of the shell with the docker process instad of waiting for it.

Based on [Suart P. Bentley's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196053) on the unix stackexchange

Alternatively you could manually listen to and act on signals using a modified version of [cuonglm's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/146770) to the same question.

Comment: I think that you are in principle correct, but the browser is somehow grabbing focus and catching the SIGINT. If I remove `xdg-open ${URL} &` form the host script, then this works. However, with that in there, it doesn't. So the problem must be there